# Use jq to concatenate JSON arrays in multiple files

Tags: json, jq

I have a series of JSON files containing an array of records, e.g.

```
$ cat f1.json
{
  "records": [
    {"a": 1},
    {"a": 3}
  ]
}

$ cat f2.json
{
  "records": [
    {"a": 2}
  ]
}
```

I want to 1) extract a single field from each record and 2) output a single array containing all the field values from all input files.

The first part is easy:

```
jq '.records | map(.a)' f?.json
[
  1,
  3
]
[
  2
]
```

But I cannot figure out how to get `jq` to concatenate those output arrays into a single array!

I'm not married to `jq`; I'll happily use another tool if necessary. But I would love to know how to do this with `jq`, because it's something I have been trying to figure out for *years*.

Comment: What another tool do you use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `-s` (or `--slurp`):

```
jq -s 'map(.records[].a)' f?.json
```

Answer (score 12):

Assuming your jq has `inputs` (which is true of jq 1.5 and later), it would be most efficient to use it, e.g. along the lines of:

```
jq -n '[inputs.records[].a]' f*.json
```

Answer (score 6):

If your input files are large, slurping the file could eat up lots of memory in which you case you can `reduce` which works in iterative manner, appending the contents of the array `.a` one object at a time

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs.records[].a as $d (.; . += [$d])' f?.json
```

The `-n` flag is to ensure to construct the output JSON from scratch with the data available from `inputs`. The `reduce` function takes the initial value of `.` which because of the null input would be just `null`. Then for each of the input objects `. += [$d]` ensures that the array contents of `.a` are appended together.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `--slurp` so that `jq` will apply its filter on the aggregation of all inputs rather than on each input. When using this option, `jq`'s input will be an array of the inputs which you need to account for.

I would use the following :

```
jq --slurp 'map(.records | map(.a)) | add' f?.json
```

We apply your current transformation to each elements of the slurped array of inputs (your previous individual inputs), then we merge those transformed arrays into one with `add`.

Comment: If your jq has `inputs` then a better alternative to using -s is to use it in conjunction with the -n command-line option.

Answer (score 3):

`--slurp` (`-s`) key is needed and `map()` to do so in one shot

```
$ cat f1.json
{
  "records": [
    {"a": 1},
    {"a": 3}
  ]
}

$ cat f2.json
{
  "records": [
    {"a": 2}
  ]
}

$ jq -s 'map(.records[].a)' f?.json
[
  1,
  3,
  2
]
```

Answer (score 2):

As a compromise between the readability of `--slurp` and the efficiency of `reduce`, you can run `jq` twice. The first is a slightly altered version of your original command, the second slurps the undifferentiated output into a single array.

```
$ jq '.records[] | .a' f?.json | jq -s
[
  1,
  3,
  2
]
```