# Using jq to concatenate directory of JSON files

Tags: json, shell, concatenation, jq

I have a directory of about 100 JSON files, each an array of 100 simple records, that I want to concatenate into one file for inclusion as static data in an app, so I don't have to make repeated API calls to retrieve small pieces. (I'm limited to downloading only 100 records at a time; that's why I have 100 short files.)

Here's a sample file, shortened to two records for display here:

```
[
 {
   "id": 11531,
   "title": "category 1",
   "count": 5
 },
 {
   "id": 11532,
   "title": "category 2",
   "count": 5
 }
]
```

My research led to a solution that works but *only* for two files with two records each:

```
jq -s '.[0] + .[1]' file1.json file2.json > output.json
```

This source also suggested this line would work to handle a directory (right now only two files in it):

```
jq -s 'reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)' json_files/* > output.json
```

but I get an error:

```
jq: error (at json_files/categories-11-20.json:0): object ({}) and array ([{"id":1153...) cannot be multiplied
```

I thought maybe the problem was the `*`trying to multiply, so I tried `+` in that place, but I get a `... cannot be added.` message.

Is there a way to do this through jq or is there a better tool?

Comment: Your two-file solution doesn't work, either; did you  mean `.[0] + .[1]`? Can you provide a sample of what your output should look like? (Do you want, for instance, a single array consisting of all the records from the individual arrays?)

Comment: If `.[0] + .[1]` does what you want, then the generalization would be `jq -s add json_files/* > output.json`.

Comment: @chepner You're right. Typo by me. I does work with the `+`  I fixed it above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest and perfectly reasonable approach would be to use the -s command-line option and `add` along the following lines:

```
jq -s add json_files/*
```

Of course you may wish to specify the list of files differently.  The order in which they are specified is also significant.

Notes:

- This Q is really just a variant of [Use jq to concatenate JSON arrays in multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60099083/use-jq-to-concatenate-json-arrays-in-multiple-files)
- `reduce` can also be used, but you would need to start with `null` or `[]` rather than `{}`.
- The operator '*' is (not surprisingly) quite different from '+'!

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks.  As a newcomer to jq, I didn't see how the answer in the link you specify could be adapted for me, as I wasn't extracting pieces. I should have played around with it. BTW, if my files are named cat1, cat2, etc. how can I specify order?

Comment: What's going on under the hood is that the `-s` flag creates an array (one file -> one item) of arrays (one record -> one item). And `add` concatenates the outer items. To specify order, you need to pipe in the files in the right order, for example using a bash loop, iterating over `cat "cat$i"` (the first `cat` is bash concatenate, the second your file name substring)

Comment: @tangobango This should do the job in order: `for i in {1..100}; do cat "cat$i"; done |  jq -s add`